# Can a data type be determined from the data paramater passed via GET/POST?

Tags: php

For example:

I Post data as `data=test`

And:

```
$myData = $_POST['data'];
```

Can the Post data be sent in a form that $myData is an array and not a string?

Something like:

```
data=array("key"=>"data")
```

I know how to set $myData as an array from the script side, so this is more of an arbitrary technical question.

Comment: could you create a less-confusing example? everthing is called `data`. Give a concrete example.

Comment: serialize() the array pass it in the url and deserialize()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use the special PHP array notation for generating an arrya, e.g.

```
example.com?foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz
               ^^---array notation
```

If it's not an array, then it's a string:

```
if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
   if (is_array($_GET['foo'])) {
      ... it's an array
   } else {
      ... it's a string
   }
|
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a request parameter (eg: form element) with the name `data[key]` with the value `data`. PHP will automatically transform this to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this as a GET URL:

```
index.php?data[]=1&data[]=2
index.php?data[a]=foo&data[b]=bar
```

or in HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='data[]' value='1' />
<input type='text' name='data[a]' value='foo' />
```

The `[]` notion numerically keys the array, while the `[a]` (etc) names keys. More can be found in [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).